# Is it possible to use SAL(Scientific Algorithm Library) in CUDA device?

Tags: c, cuda, gpu

I have some host codes in which SAL functions are incorporated. SAL functions are used to handle large data. I want to adapt the same functionality in CUDA device and analyse the execution time both at host and device. But since SAL functions are for host/CPU, how can these be allowed at the GPU or is it possible to call SAL functions from the GPU side?

For example,

```
cvabsx((COMPLEX *)in, 2, out, 1, size, 0);
```

The above SAL function computes the magnitude of complex numbers. Now I want to adapt this at the GPU side. How to do this? Or is there any other library which executes much faster than SAL?

Comment: I have never heard of SAL. Are you referring to [this open source project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opensal/)? Depending on what functions from the library you are using, CUBLAS, Thrust, or NPP may be suitable for porting the code to the GPU, along with some custom kernels maybe. It is difficult to make specific recommendations when close to nothing is known about your code.

Comment: @njuffa Yes openSAL is used only for the desktop machine, but SAL is used to port it to actual PowerPC target boards, basically for radar applications. So I was trying it out with the GPU boards, if it is portable or not..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a library that has been compiled for x86 usage (i.e. purely for host code usage, using only the host code compiler) on the device.

Obviously, GPU compatible libraries such as CUBLAS and many others can be used with a GPU. But for most ordinary compiled libraries, they cannot be used directly with GPUs in device code.

If you have access to the source code of the library, then it should be (in theory) possible to go through the library source code, and decorate functions with `__host__` `__device__` as needed, then re-compile the library source with the `nvcc` compiler, to produce a version that has functions that are usable in device code.  (If it is a templated/header library, it may just be a matter of decorating the library code, then re-compiling your application.)

Depending on the library implementation, this could be a very involved task.

Comment: Which library do you suggest me wherein I can find most of the mathematical and signal processing functions? Is it possible to work with different libraries at the same time?